# transform origin css shifting while rotating in circular way

Tags: html, css

I have created wheel and one HAND which will (transform) rotate across wheel depend on angle passed.

I have shifted angle to give more nice feel like clock's second hand

```
transform-origin:100% 80%;
```

but while rotating its shifting the radius or I have to translate too ?

CSS :

```
.wheel {
  background: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  position: relative;
/*   display:inline-block; */
  margin:20px auto;
}
/* wheel center */
.wheel:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:rgba(200,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius:10px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-top:-5px;
}


.hand {
  width: 4px;
  height: 55%;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-2px;
  margin-top:-45%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);

  /* shifted */
  transform-origin:100% 80%;
  border-radius:4px;
}
.hand:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  background:blue;
  height:10px;
  top:80%;
  left:80%;
  margin-top:-3px;
  margin-left:-6px;
  border-radius:100%;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="wheel">
  <div class="hand"></div>
</div>
```

Link : 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lfm6skqs/

Comment: Is it necessary that this uses html elements (and intends to eventually move them around)? I ask because there are ways to accomplish this using, say, a `<canvas>` element.

Comment: You mean that those two dots(red and blue) shift too?

Comment: @VilleKoo red dot is centre of circle, blue is shifting coz its on hand-line

Comment: Hmm, then i'm not quite sure what the problem is :/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfm6skqs/1/ please see in action @VilleKoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it fixed with help of "translateY" instead of changing "top" value.

So my updated code is CSS :

```
.wheel {
  background: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  position: relative;
/*   display:inline-block; */
  margin:20px auto;
}
/* wheel center */
.wheel:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:rgba(200,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius:10px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-top:-5px;
}

.hand {
  width: 4px;
  height: 55%;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-2px;
  margin-top:-55%;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(40px);

  /* shifted */
  transform-origin:50% 100%;
  border-radius:4px;

  animation: rotate-me2 5s linear infinite;
}
.hand:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  background:blue;
  height:10px;
  top:80%;
  left:80%;
  margin-top:-3px;
  margin-left:-6px;
  border-radius:100%;
}
@keyframes rotate-me {
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg) translateY(40px);}
}
```

update link is : 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lfm6skqs/2/